# Exclude a class being tree-shaken by Tailwind

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, arbitrary-values

Is there a way to exclude certain classes from being tree-shaken? The reason I ask is that in my JavaScript I'm using an [arbitrary-value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values) e.g. `bg-[url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')]` but the `url` is passed via a Vue computed property e.g.

```
`bg-[url('${this.image}')]`
```

I don't think this is being recognised, although I'm not certain.

I'm aware of how to use `tailwind.config.js` with the `purge` option, and the issue does not seem to be there, because other classes in the Vue component are included.

I'm using the `mode: 'jit'` option to allow arbitrary values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just noticed [safelisting](https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/tailwind/config#whitelisting-classes) which I am using with Nuxt. I will use this in combination with advice based on [this](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1962#issuecomment-649058002) Github issue comment by using [safelisting patterns](https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html#patterns) e.g.

```
    options: {
      safelist: {
        greedy: [
          /^bg-/
        ]
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, in my usecase, I can't use the above because of computed class names which is [not supported](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support). Instead I had to use an inline style.

Comment: greedy is an outdated feature, must use the pattern

Answer (score 4):

You can safelist classes as a last resort

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}'
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'bg-red-500',
    'text-3xl',
    'lg:text-4xl',
  ]
  // ...
}
```

More information at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Comment: It just gives the example of safelist it doesn't exactly address the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the other solutions now to the TailWind 3.1.2. On the **tailwind.config.js** insert it

```
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /^(bg-|border-|text-)/,
      variants: ["hover", "active"],
    },
  ],
```